# Mass node update

Tags: importing-exporting

I have a site containing several thousand nodes. Each node is effectively a book, in that it has a title, various content fields and a unique identifier similar to an ISBN.

I need a way of importing some data into the site via a script, using the unique identifier as a check - i.e. where ISBN = "X", update field body with "Y".

Can I do this via SQL or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a node in code, I suggest to use the [entity](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module, since it is really much easier to manipulate its entity wrapper than the default node / fields objects.

For an example of use :

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$var = $node_wrapper->field_number->value() + 1;
$node_wrapper->field_number->set($var);
$node_wrapper->save();
```

You can wrap your whole import into a transaction, to avoid errors :

```
db_query("begin;");

...

//if error
db_query("rollback;");

...

// if everything is ok
db_query("commit;");
```

All you have to do now is retrieve your nodes and loop through it :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=') // select nodes
              ->propertyCondition('type', 'news', '=') // node type
              ->propertyCondition('status', '1') // published
              ->fieldCondition('field_yourfield', 'yourfield_value', 0, '>') // your field condition
              ->execute();

$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
```

And now you have everything you need !

Edit : since you dont need to learn how to build a module just for a one-time script, you can create your own script ... but with the drupal API. You can do this with :

```
// Get the drupal path
$drupal_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// Define a DRUPAL_ROOT contant with the drupal path
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $drupal_path);

// load the bootstrap.inc file to access the drupal_bootsrap() function
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';

// Start drupal
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// You now have access to the drupal API, so you can do :
// var_dump(node_load(1));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for replying - this will take a bit of figuring out for me as I haven't written Drupal modules before. Are you suggesting I do this as a module, or as a php script?

Comment: I edited my answer